# Realm: Migrating from ObjC to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I have an app written in ObjC. I've chosen Realm as my DataBase.

I would like to start migrating some parts of my app to Swift.

When getting to Realm I get confused.

There are two `pods`. From what I understood from the docs, RealmSwift is for pure Swift projects, right?

But, is it possible to migrate model classes to Swift without the RealmSwift `pod`?

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, Realm Swift isn't exclusive for pure Swift projects, but if you do use it in an iOS app, you can't make any calls to it from any Objective-C code. So if you plan to move all of your Realm code to Swift, then it should be okay.

If you've still got any Realm code in Objective-C, then it would be better to stick with the Realm Objective-C framework, and make any Swift calls via the Swift bridging header.

Realm files are very platform independent, so if you simply rewrote the Objective-C model classes in Swift, as long as the model properties and types were exactly the same, it should still simply work.