# Porting Int Realm List from Objective-c to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

How do I porting Realm data model from Objective-c to Swift like below property?

**Objective-c**

```
@property RLMArray<NSNumber *><RLMInt> *dates;
```

**Swift** (My solution but it's not working)

```
let dates = List<Int>()
```

**Error**

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'MyDataModel.dates' has been made required."

Comment: Did you search for that error?

Comment: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'MyDataModel.dates' has been made required."

Comment: Please [edit] the question with additional info, don't add it to the comments.

Comment: Realm Lists do not handle primitives very well so avoid List<Int>. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518571/how-to-use-nspredicate-for-whether-a-list-of-int-contains-a-int-number/57527561#57527561). When you say *porting*, do you mean Migration? If not what do you mean. From the Realm Docs: *Note that querying Lists containing primitive values is currently not supported* so it's best to avoid primitives.

Comment: Also, if this is a migration situation then the underlying data is the same - there's not need to migrate underlying data. Migrations are for when you're moving data from one property to another, or wanting to combine properties into one, or changing a class name or a number of properties with a class, etc.

Comment: @Jay I have one project using Objc, and I want to create new one for iPad app using Swift. The two apps share the same data, that's why I need to porting the data models to Swift version.

Comment: The underlying Realm file is platform agnostic. It doesn't care if one app is Swift and the other is ObjC - the data remains the same, so you don't need need to migrate anything - in fact, migrating may cause the other app to break unless it's re-written. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961251/realm-migrating-from-objc-to-swift). That's why you can access the same data from a Swift, Android or Objc App.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that I just had to add **requiredProperties** method on the RLMObject subclass in Objective-c version, and it will work fine in Swift version. The reason is that the **List** type must be non-optional.

```
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)requiredProperties {
    return @[@"dates"];
}
```